# C# Formatting Settings for Visual Studio 2013 Have No Effect

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to make VS 2013 stop putting my opening braces on new lines when the code block is not a type. I've gone to *Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> New Lines* and unchecked everything except new lines for types, query expression clauses, and the keyword options.

I hit *"OK"*, and VS *STILL* keeps putting ALL my opening braces on new lines every time I finish a statement or block or otherwise trigger an auto format. I've even tried restarting VS. No luck.

The settings SAY that they are set to what I wanted, but Visual Studio refuses to obey them. **EXTREMELY** frustrating. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you happen to use ReSharper? If you do, it completely overrides what VS does, and you have to configure your formatting settings in its own options dialog.

Comment: +Lucas Trzesniewski That was it. I am using an install on a machine that another developer used before me. He apparently used ReSharper, which is something I didn't even know about. Thanks. Would you like to post that as an answer for me to accept, or should I?

Comment: Go on, post one if you'd like - after all I just tried to guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Lucas Trzesniewski in the question comments, the problem has been found and solved: ReSharper.

I'm working on a machine that another dev was using before me. They installed ReSharper into Visual Studio, which overrides VS's settings with its own. I didn't even know that ReSharper existed--hence my confusion.

For anyone else who didn't know about ReSharper, **here's how to set up your opening brace formatting**:

Go to *Tools -> Options*. In the collapsible lists on the left, go to *ReSharperPlatformVs12 -> General* and click the *Options...* button that appears on the right.

There will be another set of collapsible lists on the left of the window that pops up. In these, go to *C# -> Formatting Style -> Braces Layout*.

On the right side, you should find a set of options in a collapsible "Braces Layout" list, each with a drop-down full of all the many ways you can make it treat opening braces for that option. Go ham and set them how you wish :D